# Success/Failure of BigQueryIO.write operation

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there any way to know whether BigQueryIO.write() operation has successfully completed within the program?
It returns WriteResult but couldn't find any relevant methods in it. Or is there?

Answer (score 2):

If any operation in a pipeline fails, it is retried. If it fails repeatedly, a Batch job is terminated and marked as failed and a Streaming job continues retrying forever. The WriteResult allows you to use the InsertRetryPolicy to control how errors are retried. This allows the IO to partially succeed and indicate which rows had problems. If you don't set the InsertRetryPolicy, then a completed pipeline means that the write has successfully completed.

If this doesn't address your concerns, could you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually I have a template in which I need to perform certain actions after data has been written to BigQuery. But anything I write after p.run() method doesn't execute.(which works if I use only Dataflow Runner and not a template). So thought of performing those steps after BigQueryIO.write(). Is this possible?

Comment: I cannot see any method as insertRetryPolicy() within WriteResult. Is this something in Beam 2.2?

Comment: InsertRetryPolicy is a property of the BigQuery write. The WriteResult will be empty if everything succeeded.

Comment: How to check if it is empty?

Comment: Anybody with a working example of this? I'm also interested in executing some tasks after a BigQuerySink task.